# Couchbase client-side timeout after idle period

Tags: node.js, couchbase

NodeJs: v0.12.4
Couchbase: 2.0.8
Service deployed with PM2

Instance of the bucket is created once per service rather than once per call based on recommendation from couchbase support as instantiating and connecting bucket is expensive.

During the load everything seems to be in order with near 0 failure rate.

After couple of days of service being barely if at all in use client fails to connected to the bucket with the following error:

{"message":"Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout","code":23}

Recycling the node.js process using 'pm2 restart' resolves the issue.

Any ideas/suggestions short of re-creating instance of the bucket and re-connecting to the bucket?

Comment: My guess would be there's an intermediary which is causing the connection to be broken. Does this only happen once the idle period is over, or does this happen for each subsequent operation?

Comment: A number of firewalls and route will close idle connections without the client being informed.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions!
Considering auto-resetting bucket connections every X seconds to re-init the otherwise expensive operation.